# Apache2 reverse proxy not working

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I have a non-apache server running on http://10.0.0.1:9000. My Apache server is running on 127.0.0.1:8000. I want Apache to reverse proxy all requests to the url /app/ and pass it on to http://10.0.0.1:9000. The following is my configuration.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /app/ http://10.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse /app/ http://10.0.0.1:9000/
```

I just can't seem to get it working. No requests are being forwarded. Not sure if I need more configurations. I don't wish to redirect just proxy it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `ProxyRequests Off` is not necessary. And you probably need `ProxyPass /app/ http://10.0.0.1:9000/app/`. And are you sure you need `ProxyPassReverse`? Aside from that, can you post the access/error log entries of what happens when you do make a request, of both servers?

Comment: `ProxyRequests Off` isn't necessary, per se, but it is recommended to set it for security purposes, despite `Off` being the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http modules are loaded.  For example, something like this should be in your apache configuration:

```
LoadModule proxy_module       modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module     modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

<sup>(That example is from a CentOS 5 system)</sup>

This can vary between distributions.  For example, on Ubuntu you can enable it with the `a2enmod proxy_http` command.

Any changes to the apache configuration will require a restart or reload.